# Store persistent instance of class in padrino/sinatra controller?

Tags: web-services, controller, sinatra, server-side, padrino

I've been trying to store a persistent instance of a class in my padrino controller, but am having some headaches. I'm currently just storing it as a class variable, but I'm getting warnings that looks like:

```
warning: class variable access from toplevel
```

I tried looking up solutions to this online, but they involve class methods such as class_variable_set or class_eval, neither of which the controller has (Though it has the instance equivalents interestingly enough). Am I trying to do something that shouldn't be done? How can I keep a persistent instance of the class? I need to do so b/c the class hits an online DB and caches stuff quite often.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently Padrino controllers are not true classes- the class variables I was assigning were getting put on to some really high level class, which is why I was getting warnings. The way I fixed this was by creating a singleton class which stored the class variables and had getters for them.